# Moved Permanently error when running dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I am trying the basic helloworld example (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) and keep getting the `HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently` error whenever I try to test my code using dev_appserver.py

The 2 files I have are copied and pasted exactly from the developers.google.com site.
I have included the location of where dev_appserver.py is in both PATH and PYTHONPATH

I am running this on Linux with python 2.7.3 and appengine v1.8.4

The output on the terminal when I run this is...

```
[verma@localhost python]$ dev_appserver.py helloworld/
WARNING  2013-09-11 04:45:49,988 api_server.py:327] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-09-11 04:45:49,999 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:57128
INFO     2013-09-11 04:45:50,021 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-09-11 04:45:50,023 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
HTTPError()
HTTPError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 256, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 97, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 233, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 256, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 97, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 233, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/verma/Documents/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently
INFO     2013-09-11 04:46:01,635 module.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have a feeling I am missing something very basic but can't find it. By the way this was working a few days back and I don't remember doing anything stupid to break this :-(

Comment: any luck with this issue? I'm having the exact same issue here.

Comment: @DavidDai just answered my own question. It appears that dev_appserver does not like proxies.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Solution to Fix your Problem.

Open FILE [GAE Installation path]/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py"

Goto Line 578

Comment out the following line

# opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())

Comment: This works when you want to try your application. However if you use "appcfg.py update", network won't be reachable if you're behind a proxy.

Comment: With google appengine 1.9.18 the line number is now 595

Answer (score 1):

It appears that dev_apserver needs to contact the google app engine servers on the internet every once in a while (even if you do not ask it to check for updates). The problem I had was that it cannot access the google servers when behind a proxy (even though I have properly exported http_proxy and https_proxy).

When I use a wired network directly connected to the internet I have no problems at all.

Once dev_appserver has 'called home', it will continue to work without issue behind a proxy for a few more days, and then I get this problem again.

In the past I have noticed similar behavior when connected on wifi as well.

It appears that dev_appserver works best when on a wired network without proxies.

This is based simply on my observations; it would be great if someone could give a definitive answer to this question.